# Python3 `pandas.DataFrame.ffill()` got an exception "TypeError: No matching signature found" caused by 'dtype'

Tags: pandas, numpy, fillna, dtype, ffill

## Problem

I used `defaultdict` to specify the dtype of each column. When I tried to ffill the dataframe, I got the following error. I think the error was caused by the dtype, but **I have to specify it** because my data is too large (1394265 rows × 300 columns) and I don't have enough memory. How can I solve the problem and ffill correctly?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-feb22c34d9cb> in <cell line: 4>()
      2 dtype['timestamp']=np.int64
      3 table1=pd.read_csv(data_root+'err_reprdc_sample.csv',index_col=0,dtype=dtype)
----> 4 table1.ffill()

14 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    329                     stacklevel=find_stack_level(),
    330                 )
--> 331             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    332 
    333         # error: "Callable[[VarArg(Any), KwArg(Any)], Any]" has no

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in ffill(self, axis, inplace, limit, downcast)
  11781         downcast: dict | None = None,
  11782     ) -> DataFrame | None:
> 11783         return super().ffill(axis=axis, inplace=inplace, limit=limit, downcast=downcast)
  11784 
  11785     @overload

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    329                     stacklevel=find_stack_level(),
    330                 )
--> 331             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    332 
    333         # error: "Callable[[VarArg(Any), KwArg(Any)], Any]" has no

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in ffill(self, axis, inplace, limit, downcast)
   6985             Object with missing values filled or None if ``inplace=True``.
   6986         """
-> 6987         return self.fillna(
   6988             method="ffill", axis=axis, inplace=inplace, limit=limit, downcast=downcast
   6989         )

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    329                     stacklevel=find_stack_level(),
    330                 )
--> 331             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    332 
    333         # error: "Callable[[VarArg(Any), KwArg(Any)], Any]" has no

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in fillna(self, value, method, axis, inplace, limit, downcast)
   5633         downcast: dict | None = None,
   5634     ) -> DataFrame | None:
-> 5635         return super().fillna(
   5636             value=value,
   5637             method=method,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in fillna(self, value, method, axis, inplace, limit, downcast)
   6811                 return result
   6812 
-> 6813             new_data = self._mgr.interpolate(
   6814                 method=method,
   6815                 axis=axis,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in interpolate(self, **kwargs)
    420 
    421     def interpolate(self: T, **kwargs) -> T:
--> 422         return self.apply("interpolate", **kwargs)
    423 
    424     def shift(self: T, periods: int, axis: int, fill_value) -> T:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in apply(self, f, align_keys, ignore_failures, **kwargs)
    350                     applied = b.apply(f, **kwargs)
    351                 else:
--> 352                     applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
    353             except (TypeError, NotImplementedError):
    354                 if not ignore_failures:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py in interpolate(self, method, axis, index, inplace, limit, limit_direction, limit_area, fill_value, downcast, **kwargs)
   1256         data = cast(np.ndarray, data)  # bc overridden by ExtensionBlock
   1257 
-> 1258         missing.interpolate_array_2d(
   1259             data,
   1260             method=method,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/missing.py in interpolate_array_2d(data, method, axis, index, limit, limit_direction, limit_area, fill_value, coerce, downcast, **kwargs)
    237             raise ValueError("Cannot pass both fill_value and method")
    238 
--> 239         interpolate_2d(
    240             data,
    241             method=m,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/missing.py in interpolate_2d(values, method, axis, limit, limit_area)
    813     # _pad_2d and _backfill_2d both modify tvalues inplace
    814     if method == "pad":
--> 815         _pad_2d(tvalues, limit=limit)
    816     else:
    817         _backfill_2d(tvalues, limit=limit)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/missing.py in new_func(values, limit, mask)
    847             return result.view(values.dtype), mask
    848 
--> 849         return func(values, limit=limit, mask=mask)
    850 
    851     return cast(F, new_func)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/missing.py in _pad_2d(values, limit, mask)
    879 
    880     if np.all(values.shape):
--> 881         algos.pad_2d_inplace(values, mask, limit=limit)
    882     else:
    883         # for test coverage

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/algos.pyx in pandas._libs.algos.__pyx_fused_cpdef()

TypeError: No matching signature found
```

## Reproduce the problem

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict

data_root='./'
dtype=defaultdict(np.float16)
dtype['timestamp']=np.int64
table1=pd.read_csv(data_root+'err_reprdc_sample.csv',index_col=0,dtype=dtype)
table1.ffill()
```

You can download the [sample file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14rcHvQjkBYHv-3huTID0PS0V8Y_qLXOz/view?usp=sharing) called 'err_reprdc_sample' and adjust the `data_root`.

| timestamp | 000001.XSHE | 000002.XSHE | 000596.XSHE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20220628092500000 | 14.47 |  |  |
| 20220628092500010 |  | 18.5 |  |
| 20220628092500020 |  |  | 234.1 |
| 20220628092500040 |  |  |  |
| 20220628092500050 |  |  |  |

## What I have tried

```py
table1=pd.read_csv(data_root+'err_reprdc_sample.csv',index_col=0)
table1.ffill()
```

**or Changing `np.float16` to `np.float32` works fine but it will take too much memory.**

Comment: `np.iinfo` provides info for integer dtypes. `np.half` is a float; `np.finfo(np.half)`

Comment: @hpaulj Oh right, sorry for the stupid problem. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
table1.convert_dtypes().ffill()
```

**Or:**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict

data_root = './'
dtype = defaultdict(np.float64)  # Use np.float64 instead of np.float16
dtype['timestamp'] = np.int64
table1 = pd.read_csv(
    data_root+'err_reprdc_sample.csv',
    index_col=0,
    dtype=dtype,
)
table1.ffill()
```

#### Explanation

The type `np.float16` can sometimes behave unpredictably with certain pandas operations, as it is not as widely supported or tested as `np.float32` or `np.float64`. Your code is not working because of that.

In the first solution, I'm simply converting the data types prior to calling `ffill`. In the second solution, I've replaced `np.float16` with `np.float64`. Both modifications to the original code were made due to the reason previously stated.

Comment: Yes, your solution works, but my memory runs out, haha. The most stupid way I can think of is to split the data frame and process them separately.

Comment: @EvanHong, have you tried using `dtype = defaultdict(np.float32)`? If that doesn’t work neither, you might consider using `PySpark` instead of Pandas. The newest versions of `PySpark` even have a copy of `Pandas` built-in

Comment: Yes, I tried. Even though it works well and solves the problem, it consumes too much memory.